# UIImage Caching: Performance Consequences Only?

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiimage

Intuitively, I've always felt that using the caching UIImage initialization (`imageNamed`) is not just a time-saver when loading from disk. It's also, I thought, a memory issue: instead of having several different `UIImage` instances with similar data, that data gets loaded into memory once.

Does using `imageNamed` result in more efficient **memory** use?

Comment: Yes, but it is not always possible: only for files from your project. You can use `NSCache` for other cases.

Comment: @Nekto thanks, I actually implemented a cache without knowing about `NSCache`... I might have to redo that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it results in more efficient memory usage too.

According to the `imageNamed:` documentation:

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the
>   specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching
>   image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image
>   data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the
>   resulting object.

The key here is that it "looks in the system caches for an image **object**".

And, just to confirm, I made a sample project with five image view's and a button.  When calling `imageNamed` five times to set all five, my heap grew 19.5k in Instruments.  Using `imageWithContentsOfFile:`, it grew 66.5k.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for contemplating this and even making a sample project. I'll mark this as accepted answer in a day or two, just want to see if this is the last word on this. +1 for now

Comment: What so crazy about this is that if the cache gets dumped with each memory warn, you actually get worse memory use from warn to warn, right?

Comment: I would guess that it is simply retaining the object that it creates and it wouldnt deallocate it unless there are no more references to it, in which case it makes no difference from a memory perspective.

Comment: Until you create it again using `imageNamed` and it doesn't have one because it released it. Then your memory use starts to grow BECAUSE you had a memory warn, right?

Comment: What I was trying to say is that I doubt that they release it unless there are no other references to it since doing so wouldn't reduce the memory footprint anyway, and it would prevent just this type of situation that you are describing.

Comment: So you think that NSCache can tell how many "handles" there are on an object and release it based on that? I thought that none of the Cocoa classes have special powers (like we're not allowed to rely on retainCount because it's wrong), but now I'm intrigued.

Comment: WE can't use the retain count like this, but Apple can (and obviously does, otherwise nothing would EVER get deallocated).  :-)

Comment: So a dev implementing their own cache is bound to fail. I ask because I am that developer, and failing here is really hard to detect.

Comment: Yeah, short of making users of your class checkin/checkout objects and basically implementing your own retain counts, I'm not sure how you would know when it is safe to release an object.